# ionic app with angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

this is my controller:

```
angular.module('app.controllers', [])

.controller('rServationCtrl', function($scope) {

})

.controller('voitureCtrl',['$scope' ,'Voiture', function($scope,Voiture) {

$scope.VoituresData = Voiture.getVoituresData();
console.log($scope.VoituresData);
}])
```

and this is my service:

```
angular.module('app.services', [])


.factory('Voiture', [function(){

var VoituresData = JSON.parse([
  {
    "idVoiture": 123,
    "numChassee": 1234,
    "numImmatricule": "120",
    "kilometrage": 0,
    "photo": null,
    "couleur": "Noire",
    "nbPlaces": 5,
    "categorie": "sport",
    "date_assurance": "2016-07-28T00:00:00.000Z",
    "date_vignette": "2016-07-28T00:00:00.000Z",
    "date_visite_tecknique": "2016-06-30T00:00:00.000Z",
    "prixLocation": 1500,
    "disponibilite": true,
    "Modele_idModele": 123457,
    "Modele": {
      "idModele": 123457,
      "nom": "A4",
      "marque": "Audi",
      "carburant": "Essence",
      "puissance": 4,
      "prixGPS": 25,
      "prixChaisse": 25,
      "prixChauffeur": 25
    }
  },  {
    "idVoiture": 150,
    "numChassee": null,
    "numImmatricule": null,
    "kilometrage": 10000,
    "photo": null,
    "couleur": null,
    "nbPlaces": null,
    "categorie": "sport",
    "date_assurance": "2016-06-17T00:00:00.000Z",
    "date_vignette": "2016-06-24T00:00:00.000Z",
    "date_visite_tecknique": "2016-03-26T00:00:00.000Z",
    "prixLocation": null,
    "disponibilite": null,
    "Modele_idModele": 123456,
    "Modele": {
      "idModele": 123456,
      "nom": " 508",
      "marque": "PEUGEOT",
      "carburant": "Essence",
      "puissance": 4,
      "prixGPS": 25,
      "prixChaisse": 25,
      "prixChauffeur": 25
    }
  }
]);


function getVoituresData (){
    return VoituresData;
}
return{
 getVoituresData : getVoituresData
};


}]);
```

and i include my controller in the html view and all script in index.html and i have this error in the console

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token o
    at Object.parse (native)
    at Object.<anonymous> ([http://localhost:8100/js/services.js:6:25)
    at Object.invoke (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:17762:17)
    at Object.enforcedReturnValue \[as $get\] (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:17615:37)
    at Object.invoke (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:17762:17)
    at http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:17580:37
    at getService (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:17721:39)
    at invoke (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:17753:13)
    at Object.instantiate (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:17770:27)
    at http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:22326:28(anonymous function) @ ionic.bundle.js:25642(anonymous function) @ ionic.bundle.js:22421Scope.$broadcast @ ionic.bundle.js:29479$state.transition.resolved.then.$state.transition @ ionic.bundle.js:49321processQueue @ ionic.bundle.js:27879(anonymous function) @ ionic.bundle.js:27895Scope.$eval @ ionic.bundle.js:29158Scope.$digest @ ionic.bundle.js:28969Scope.$apply @ ionic.bundle.js:29263(anonymous function) @ ionic.bundle.js:31030completeOutstandingRequest @ ionic.bundle.js:18706(anonymous function) @ ionic.bundle.js:18978][1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to change JSON.parse() parameter. It should be string.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

```
var VoituresData = JSON.parse('[
  {
    "idVoiture": 123,
    "numChassee": 1234,
    "numImmatricule": "120",
    "kilometrage": 0,
    "photo": null,
    "couleur": "Noire",
    "nbPlaces": 5,
    "categorie": "sport",
    "date_assurance": "2016-07-28T00:00:00.000Z",
    "date_vignette": "2016-07-28T00:00:00.000Z",
    "date_visite_tecknique": "2016-06-30T00:00:00.000Z",
    "prixLocation": 1500,
    "disponibilite": true,
    "Modele_idModele": 123457,
    "Modele": {
      "idModele": 123457,
      "nom": "A4",
      "marque": "Audi",
      "carburant": "Essence",
      "puissance": 4,
      "prixGPS": 25,
      "prixChaisse": 25,
      "prixChauffeur": 25
    }
  },  {
    "idVoiture": 150,
    "numChassee": null,
    "numImmatricule": null,
    "kilometrage": 10000,
    "photo": null,
    "couleur": null,
    "nbPlaces": null,
    "categorie": "sport",
    "date_assurance": "2016-06-17T00:00:00.000Z",
    "date_vignette": "2016-06-24T00:00:00.000Z",
    "date_visite_tecknique": "2016-03-26T00:00:00.000Z",
    "prixLocation": null,
    "disponibilite": null,
    "Modele_idModele": 123456,
    "Modele": {
      "idModele": 123456,
      "nom": " 508",
      "marque": "PEUGEOT",
      "carburant": "Essence",
      "puissance": 4,
      "prixGPS": 25,
      "prixChaisse": 25,
      "prixChauffeur": 25
    }
  }
]');
```

Comment: i chage it but i have this error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Comment: thinks i fixed it :)